# NextJS: Prefer hard coded over dynamic route

Tags: javascript, next.js

Any way to prefer pages/hello over pages/[slug] where slug = hello . They're the same route, can Next differentiate between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. It is specifically mentioned as a caveat of dynamic routes in the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats).

Your predefined `/hello` will take precedence over dynamic `/hello`

Comment: Great answer, thanks, i missed that when looking through the docs. Unfortunately, it currently fails on build due to these routes being identical so I'll have to figure out how I can get it to build

Answer (score 0):

You have to create pages folder and if you create hello.js and it can be access /hello you can find more info on nextjs doc page

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages